# Is it possible to write a custom converter for Pandoc?

Tags: pandoc

Is it possible to write a custom output writer for Pandoc?

For example, suppose I want to convert a document:

```
pandoc -f markdown -t myCustomMarkup asdf.md
```

Does Pandoc have a way I can specify the conversion rules for `myCustomMarkup`? (e.g. I could specify that text that had the 'bold' attribute should map to `<bold>text</bold>`, and so on for all features/attributes that Pandoc recognises).

Can anyone point me to some documentation as to how I can implement my own?
I can't seem to find any mention of this.

(Additionally, is there a way to "plug in" a writer defined in a file without having to (say) re-compile pandoc? e.g. `pandoc -f markdown -t myCustomMarkup --writerpath=path/to/my/writer asdf.md`)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's no easy way to do this with current pandoc, but the next version of pandoc will contain code that allows you to write custom writers with a bit of easy lua scripting.  (The code for this is already in the `master` branch in http://github.com/jgm/pandoc.)  You'll be able to do

```
pandoc -t myfunkyformat.lua myfile.md
```

Here's an example of what a custom writer script might look like:
https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/blob/master/data/sample.lua

You can use the code now if you compile from source:
https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/wiki/Installing-the-development-version-of-pandoc

Comment: Last link is broken. Would it be possible to create a converter-extension, that removes custom parts of a document (e.g between something like `<!-- <myexclusion> --> .. <!-- </myexclusion> -->` for markdown), before passing it on to the standard converter for that input format?

Comment: See https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/blob/master/data/sample.lua
(I'll edit the post above).

Comment: And yes, you could write a converter that does what you describe.  The html comments would be passed to RawBlock, which could be told to set a global variable.  The other functions could check this variable and emit no output if it is set.  The variable could be reset when the end tag is reached.

Comment: What about Haskell? Is it possible to write a custom writer in Haskell without rebuilding the whole pandoc package?

Comment: I'm also a little confused about the difference between Lua custom writers and another Haskell writer as mentioned by @finite